# Converting String to Currency Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, currency-formatting

I am having trouble converting my array of String to Currency.

[image]

[image]

I have created an extension `currencyInputFormatting()`. However, the commas are being placed in the wrong spots.

Here is my code :-

```
cell.balanceLabel.text? = (monthlyBalanceStringArray)[indexPath.row].currencyFormatting()

extension String {

    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyFormatting() -> String {

        var number: NSNumber!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

        var amountWithPrefix = self

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

        let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double))

        //    number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

        guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
            return ""
        }

        return formatter.string(from: number)!
    }
}
```

Comment: _"the commas are being placed in the wrong spots."_ What do you mean? Can you please give an example of inputs, and expected and actual outputs. Also, always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to replace any any characters using regex. Just use `NSNumberFormatter`

```
extension String {
    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyFormatting() -> String {
        if let value = Double(self) {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
            if let str = formatter.string(for: value) {
                return str
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

---

```
"74154.7".currencyFormatting()            // $74,154.70

"74719.4048014544".currencyFormatting()   // $74,719.40
```

Comment: you can use `string(for:value)` directly, no need for `NSNumber`.

Comment: Try "10.k1".currencyFormatting() with this code. It will fail. Wrong answer.

The input is an array of string. You can't assume it to be correct.

Comment: This will create a new NumberFormatter object every time you call this method.

Comment: Note that if the goal is to display the currency in US$ you would need also to set a fixed locale to your formatter otherwise 100 dollars might became 100 euros.

Answer (score 3):

> **You can use following function for valid currency format -**

```
 extension Int {
    func createCurrencyString() -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self))!
    }
}
```